# Tiles Stacking Problem to build a stable stack

Tags: c++, algorithm, dynamic-programming

I am studying Dynamic Programming on GeeksForGeeks and have a problem with Tiles Stacking Problem and the way it is solved

> A stable tower of height n is a tower consisting of exactly n tiles of unit height stacked vertically in such a way, that no bigger tile is placed on a smaller tile. An example is shown below :

[image]

> We have infinite number of tiles of sizes 1, 2, …, m. The task is calculate the number of different stable tower of height n that can be built from these tiles, with a restriction that you can use at most k tiles of each size in the tower.

> Note: Two tower of height n are different if and only if there exists a height h (1 <= h <= n), such that the towers have tiles of different sizes at height h.
> For example:

> ```
> Input : n = 3, m = 3, k = 1.
> Output : 1
> Possible sequences: { 1, 2, 3}. 
> Hence answer is 1.
>
> Input : n = 3, m = 3, k = 2.
> Output : 7
> {1, 1, 2}, {1, 1, 3}, {1, 2, 2},
> {1, 2, 3}, {1, 3, 3}, {2, 2, 3}, 
> {2, 3, 3}.
> ```

The way to solve is to count number of decreasing sequences of length n using numbers from 1 to m where every number can be used at most k times. We can recursively compute count for n using count for n-1.

Declare a 2D array dp[][], where each state dp[i][j] denotes the number of decreasing sequences of length i using numbers from j to m. We need to take care of the fact that a number can be used a most k times. This can be done by considering 1 to k occurrences of a number. Hence our recurrence relation becomes:

[image]

Also, we can use the fact that for a fixed j we are using the consecutive values of previous k values of i. Hence, we can maintain a prefix sum array for each state. Now we have got rid of the k factor for each state.

I have read this algorithm for many times but I don't understand it and how to prove the accuracy of it. I have tried to find the guide on the internet but only its variations. Please help me to explain it.

Answer (score 0):

- Observe that the largest size tile (`m`) can appear only at the bottom.
- Its appearances are **consecutive**
- Your recurrence becomes:

```
T(n,m,k) = SIGMA_{i=0,...,k} T(n-i,m-1,k)
```

- Then you have to define the base cases of the recurrence:

```
T(n,m,1) = // can you tell what this is?
T(n,1,k) = // can you tell what this is?
T(1,m,k) = m // this is easy
```

Comment: Excuse me but I can not get the idea of the recurrence here, how do you prove the recurrence here?

Comment: The tile of size `m` can only appear at the bottom of the tower. The number of (consecutive) appearances is between `0` and `k`. After that, we get the same problem, with maximal element `m-1` and length `n-i` where `i` is the number of `m`-tiles

Comment: The final case for T(1, m, k) I think that it is 1 not, m. How do you think that?

Comment: @HoangNam if we are allowed only one tile and have m sizes to choose from (i.e., T(1, m, k)), we can construct m different stacks, each one with just one tile of a different size.

Answer (score 0):

We can prove it by forming a logical recurrence:

(A) If the maximum stack height, given m and k is smaller than n, we cannot create any stack.

(B) If only one tile is allowed, we can choose m different sizes for that tile.

(C) If only one size is allowed, if k is greater than or equal to n, we can construct one stack of n tiles of size 1; otherwise, zero stacks.

(D) For each possible count, x, of tiles of size m stacked, we have one way that is multiplied by the number of ways to stack (n - x) tiles, using sizes of at most (m - 1) since we used m.

To convert the recurrence to bottom-up dynamic programming, we initialise the matrix using the base cases of the recurrence, and fill in subsequent entries using its general-case logical branch.

Here's a demonstration of the recurrence in JavaScript (sorry I'm not versed in C++ but the first function, `f`, which calculates just the count, should be very easy to convert):

```js
// Returns the count
function f(n, m, k){
  if (n > m * k)
    return 0;
  
  if (n == 1)
    return m;
    
  if (m == 1)
    return n <= k ? 1 : 0;
   
  let result = 0;

  for (let x=0; x<=k; x++)
    result += f(n - x, m - 1, k);
    
  return result;
}

// Returns the sequences
function g(n, m, k){
  if (n > m * k)
    return [];
  
  if (n == 1)
    return new Array(m).fill(0).map((_, i) => [i + 1]);
    
  if (m == 1)
    return n <= k ? [new Array(n).fill(1)] : [];
   
  let result = [];

  for (let x=0; x<=k; x++){
    const pfx = new Array(x).fill(m);
    const prev = g(n - x, m - 1, k);

    for (let s of prev)
      result.push(pfx.concat(s));
  }
    
  return result;
}

var inputs = [
  [3, 3, 1],
  [3, 3, 2],
  [1, 2, 2]
];

for (let args of inputs){
  console.log('' + args);
  console.log(f(...args));
  console.log(JSON.stringify(g(...args)));
  console.log('');
}
```